# Checking if a string is in a string Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this bash script that will run `Xvfb` I need to check if it's installed or if I need to delete a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DOESNT_EXIST="bash: /usr/bin/Xvfb: No such file or directory"
EXISTS="Fatal server error:"
RESULT="$(Xvfb | awk '{print $1}')"

if ${RESULT} =~ .*${DOESNT_EXIST}.* ; then
  sudo apt-get install xvfb
elif ${RESULT} =~ .*${EXISTS}.* ; then
  sudo rm -rf /tmp/.X0-lock
  sudo apt-get purge xvfb
  sudo apt-get install xvfb
fi
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already active for display 0
        If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
        and start again.
(EE) 
etc/scripts/fix_pie.sh: 7: etc/scripts/fix_pie.sh: =~: not found
etc/scripts/fix_pie.sh: 9: etc/scripts/fix_pie.sh: =~: not found
```

I don't understand what is wrong here, how can I fix this to do what I want it to do?

Comment: Regex matching has to go into `[[ ]]`; you don't need `.*` at the beginning and end; you could just use `grep -q`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. That would output `etc/scripts/fix_pie.sh: 7: etc/scripts/fix_pie.sh: [[: not found
etc/scripts/fix_pie.sh: 9: etc/scripts/fix_pie.sh: [[: not found`

Comment: @BenjaminW. Also with grep it tells me `permission denied`

Comment: Are you doing this? `if [[ $RESULT =~ $DOESNT_EXIST ]]; then`? And for grep, are you doing `if grep -q "$DOESNT_EXIST" <<< "$RESULT"; then`?